# Cursor doesn't print text when I tell it to

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursors

I have used `WAITFOR` combined with a cursor in the following script:

```
create table orders(orderId int primary key,productId int,productName varchar(20));

insert into orders values(1,11,'book');
insert into orders values(2,13,'flower');
insert into orders values(3,24,'microwave');
insert into orders values(4,7,'food');
insert into orders values(5,46,'clothes');

declare cur cursor for   
select * from orders;
open cur;
fetch next from cur;
while(@@fetch_status=0)
begin
    waitfor delay '00:00:01';
    fetch next from cur;
end;
close cur;
deallocate cur;
```

I'm looking to display one record from the cursor per the specified interval of 1 second. For example: display the first row, then wait a second; display the second row, then wait a second; and so on. The cursor above does not do that. Say `orders` has 5 rows. The `WHILE` block waits 5 seconds and then displays all records together.

Is this the cursor's fault?  How can I modify this script to work as intended?

Answer (score 7):

Add `RAISERROR('', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT` before the delay to flush anything in the buffer to the client (SSMS?) first otherwise SQL Server will wait for more data to fill the packet.

```
Declare cur cursor for   
select * from orders   
open cur
fetch next from cur
while(@@fetch_status=0)
begin
    RAISERROR('', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
    fetch next from cur
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you cant use WAITFOR within a cursor, as I found out to my dismay.
Best solution would be to rewrite the query without a CURSOR...?

Comment: Yes you can. [screenshot of it all working fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G78ws.png)